# How to add a custom success message to Magento newsletter form?

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter, messages, success-message

I added a newsletter form on a CMS page and I created a new template to show the  form.  I was wondering if there is a way to display a custom success message for just that one form?

It seems I remember seeing a way by using javascript but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it clean, the success newsletter message is stored in newsletter controller : `Mage_Newsletter_SubscriberController` > `newAction()`function > `$session->addSuccess($this->__('Thank you for your subscription.'));`.

So if you want to customize this message just for one form your have to this:

1) Rewrite the controller in your local, from : `app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/controllers/SubscriberController.php` to your local codepool.

2) Create a new function, you call it for example `customnewAction()`:

```
public function customnewAction()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getPost('email')) {
        $session            = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
        $customerSession    = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        $email              = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('email');

        try {
            if (!Zend_Validate::is($email, 'EmailAddress')) {
                Mage::throwException($this->__('Please enter a valid email address.'));
            }

            if (Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::XML_PATH_ALLOW_GUEST_SUBSCRIBE_FLAG) != 1 && 
                !$customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
                Mage::throwException($this->__('Sorry, but administrator denied subscription for guests. Please <a href="%s">register</a>.', Mage::helper('customer')->getRegisterUrl()));
            }

            $ownerId = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                        ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
                        ->loadByEmail($email)
                        ->getId();
            if ($ownerId !== null && $ownerId != $customerSession->getId()) {
                Mage::throwException($this->__('This email address is already assigned to another user.'));
            }

            $status = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($email);
            if ($status == Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
                $session->addSuccess($this->__('Confirmation request has been sent.'));
            }
            else {
            $session->addSuccess($this->__('YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE HERE.'));
            }
        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $session->addException($e, $this->__('There was a problem with the subscription: %s', $e->getMessage()));
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $session->addException($e, $this->__('There was a problem with the subscription.'));
        }
    }
    $this->_redirectReferer();
}
```

3) Create your **custom Newsletter** template in : `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/newsletter/custom_subscribe.phtml` then put inside the code bellow:

```
<div class="block block-subscribe">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Newsletter') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('newsletter/subscriber/customnew'); ?>" method="post" id="newsletter-validate-detail">
        <div class="block-content">
            <div class="form-subscribe-header">
                <label for="newsletter"><?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Our Newsletter:') ?></label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
               <input type="text" name="email" id="newsletter" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Sign up for our newsletter')) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" />
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Subscribe')) ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Subscribe') ?></span></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-validate-detail');
    //]]>
    </script>
</div>
```

> **nb**: the form action of this custom newsletter call the new function that we created in step 2) `<form action="<?php echo
>   $this->getUrl('newsletter/subscriber/customnew'); ?> ...`

4) If you want to display this new Newsletter form in your CMS page you have to put this code inside:

```
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="custom.newsletter" template="newsletter/custom_subscribe.phtml"}}
```

5) Clear your Magento cache and you'll get what you want.